# How to get number of if block execute count

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with attendance management system in php. I try to create report for employee.in case some person late(LP) come between 15 min and 30 min it should be recorded as late present and if mod(Late present count/3) = 0 should be record as Short leave(SL) how do this task ? Other states are recorded very fine.

```
if($row['Time_in'] > $earliest_arrival_time && $row['Time_in'] <= $shift_start_time){

    $table .='<td border border-dark>' . 'P' . '</td>';

}elseif($row['Time_in'] > $shift_start_time && $row['Time_in'] <= $shift_start_time_new){

    $table .='<td border border-dark>' . 'P' . '</td>';

}elseif ($row['Time_in'] > $shift_start_time_new && $row['Time_in'] <= $shift_start_time_new02 ){

     $table .='<td border border-dark>' . 'LP' . '</td>';//need the check above mention logic in here

}elseif ($row['Time_in'] > $shift_start_time_new02 && $row['Time_in'] <= $lastest_arrival_time){

     $table .='<td border border-dark>' . 'SL' . '</td>';
}
```

how do get the LP printed time?and how to apply the logic?

```
$row['Time_in'] = 08:50:00 (this change time to time)
$earliest_arrival_time =03:00:00
$shift_start_time = 08:30:00
$shift_start_time_new = 08:45:00($shift_start_time + 15 min)
$shift_start_time_new02 = 09:00:00($shift_start_time + 30 min)
$lastest_arrival_time = 12:15:00
```

Comment: can you make an example with values for all variable, so i ll understand more beter and help you to achieve this.

Comment: okay .i will change

Comment: please add input and expected output

Comment: done.i update my question

Comment: I have post an answer, pls see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $count = 0;            
       foreach($rows as $row){

            if(!empty($row['time_in'])){

              if($row['time_in'] <= $shift_start_time) {

                echo 'present';


             } else if($row['time_in'] > $shift_start_time  && $row['time_in'] >= $shift_start_time_new && $row['time_in'] <= $shift_start_time_new02 ) {

              $count++;

              if($count%3 == 0){

                echo 'short leave'

              } else {

                echo 'late present';

              }



             } else {

              echo 'very late';

             } 


          } else {

            echo 'absent';
          }


      }            



       I do not understand this variable $earliest_arrival_time
```